# Razor - Importing Namespaces that Can't Be Found

Tags: c#, razor, namespaces

I am currently working with a solution that contains a C# project and a Razor web page project. I am looking to import a namespace from that C# project to the web page but it gives an error saying that the namespace could not be found. The namespaces in the project are structured "CompanyName.WordThatDescribesNamespace". When I say `@using Company.Namespace` it says that there is no namespace called Company. Is using that period preventing it from importing the namespace or is there a way around it?

Comment: So what is the actual namespace - "Company" or "CompanyName"?

Comment: Have you checked your references to this project? this type of errors usually means you should refer to a external library in your csproj file.

Comment: @Andrei the name of the namespace is "Company.Something"

Comment: @legrandviking Well thank you for making me feel stupid, turns out I did forget to add the reference. Thank You!

Comment: @GPinsky It happens to the best of us once in a while, main reason i mentionned it is that i had the same problem lately

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understood this following this.

1. You have two projects in a solution
2. One is a class project (dll) and another one is an MVC project.

You need to access the methods in class project to the MVC.

Please make sure you did the following things
1. Added reference to the dll of the class project having `CompanyName.WordThatDescribesNamespace`. You can got to Solution Explorer and verify this.
2. If referred , please check the properties, whether you set `CopyLocal=True`. Deletes the dlls in Bin folder and try to refer and changing it to `False` and build the project.
3. You can also add namespace to the Web.config residing in the Views folder, so it will be available for all views.

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />

    ...

    <add namespace="Infragistics.Web.Mvc" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Hope any one of the above helps you.